# Space Invaders AI Shooter UNITY3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Traigo una duda sobre la IA de Spaces Invaders:

Si ven abajo en las imagenes del juego, los invaders a la hora de disparar, **disparan los más cercanos al jugador en forma de grilla**

Es decir: siempre comenzarán disparando lo de la primera línea, pero si logro matar a cualquiera de la primera linea, el que está detrás, es quien comenzará a disparar.

Hice un script que lo resuelve, pero no estoy seguro si es del todo, la mejor solución:

```
public void bulletAI()
{
    invaderList = new List<GameObject> GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Shooter"));

    var lastId = invaderList.FirstOrDefault(o => 
            o.transform.position.x >= player.transform.position.x);

    Instantiate(invaderProjectile, 
                lastId.transform.position, 
                lastId.transform.rotation);

}
```

¿Alguno se ha topado con algo así? ¡Cualquier feedback será bienvenido!

PD: Lo siento por ponerlo en inglés, no me di cuenta que era Stack Overflow Español jaja. Abrazos desde Argentina!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) may be another option

Comment: Yo pienso que cuando tu escribe 'o.x > player.x', es possible que un invader es mas cercano si tu escribe 'o.x < player.x'. (el invader puede ser izquierda o derecha).

Comment: En realidad, si utilizo que sea  o.x <  player.x, sólo dispara de a uno, el primero de la grilla, y va correlativo hacia arriba. Pero si es >=  disparan todos los más cercanos de eje X e Y, porque deben disparar de a 5 como máximo, entonces, si pongo que sea menor a player.x, sólo dispara de a 1 en eje Y.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, no entendí muy bien la idea, pero me arriesgaré a dar una solución con lo que entendí.

Si es un juego 2d y usas coordenadas (x,y), usa Vector2.Distance para calcular la distancia de cada enemigo en relación al player:
Por ejemplo el enemigo tendría esta linea:

```
float distance = Vector2.Distance( player.transform.position, transform.position );
```

Así se puede obtener la distancia que hay entre el player y el enemigo.

*Espero te sirva.*